# Using Thread with Parameter as object

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you start a thread with `object` as a parameter in C#.

I wanted to pass the `object` as the parameter to the `Thread` Function.

Comment: Show us what you've got. In most cases, you don't need to pass 'the Object' because your thread function is a member function.

Comment: Refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1083/Multithreaded-Programming-Using-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass a parameter to a thread use [`ParametrizedThreadStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParametrizedThreadStart(func));
thread.Start(obj);
```

The **`ParameterizedThreadStart`** delegate and the `Thread.Start(Object)` method overload make it easy *to pass data to a thread procedure*.

Answer (score 1):

```
var thread = new Thread(() => Method(parameter));
thread.Start();
```